# Java Bank Example

Tags: java, hashmap

```
package nimit.bank;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class MDB {

public final static int entityCustomer=1;
public static HashMap<Object, Object> hmapCustomer = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
public final static int entityAccount=2;
public static HashMap<Object, Object> hmapAccount = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
public final static int entityBank=3;
public static HashMap<Object, Object> hmapBank = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

public static Object get(int entity,Object key) {
Object obj=null;
switch(entity){
case entityCustomer: obj=hmapCustomer.get(key);
break;
case entityAccount: obj=hmapAccount.get(key);
break;
case entityBank: obj=hmapBank.get(key);
break;
}
return obj   
}   
public static void put(int entity, Object key,Object obj ){       
switch(entity){
case entityCustomer: hmapCustomer.put(key,obj);
break;
case entityAccount: hmapAccount.put(key, obj);
break;
case entityBank: hmapBank.put(key,obj);
break;
}
  }
}
```

This is a bank example and I use hashmaps to store the data. I have created a Customer.java class as below.

package nimit.bank;

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private long phone_no;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public long getPhone_No() {
        return phone_no;
    }

    public Customer(String _Name, String _Address, long _phone) {
        name = _Name;
        address = _Address;
        phone_no = _phone;
    }
}
```

I have created a BankController.java class to input the data and retrieve it.

package nimit.bank;

```
public class BankController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer C = new Customer("nimit", "Jane Street", 26711610);
        Object key = 54321;
        MDB.put(MDB.entityCustomer, key, C);

        System.out.println(MDB.get(MDB.entityCustomer, key));
    }
}
```

My doubt is, the **System.out.println(MDB.get(MDB.entityCustomer,key));** gives null as the output. I'm not able to understand. I'm passing the key as Object type.

Comment: why are you not adding a break after each case?

Comment: Its a good practice to avoid any shocks later on. Anyway I ran your program and I got the customer object

Comment: I did the same but got __nimit.bank.Customer@231bf785__ as the output

Comment: you need to override `toString()` ...

Comment: Yeap. So what are you expecting? Cast it to your object and then get the values from Pojo something like this  System.out.println(((Customer)MDB.get(MDB.entityCustomer,key)).getName());

Comment: Oh Ok. Got it. I better go through the documentation again. Thank you I really appreciate the help.